NGINX downloads PHP file instead of rendering it as PHP
I am trying to render or display my PHP files from different directories within my app/project folder. I am using a different browser to try visiting specific routes, but it downloads the file instead of rendering it as PHP.
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Panel: CloudPanel
PHP Version: 8.3
cgi.fix_pathinfo: 0
Current VHOST/NGINX config:
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 quic;
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 quic;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  http2 on;
  http3 off;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name ***.com www1.***.com;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  include /etc/nginx/global_settings;

  index index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:{{app_port}}/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout 900;
    proxy_send_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }
}

Whenever I visit ***.com/admin, it only downloads the osa_main.php script.
index.js osa route function:
...
app.get('/osa', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'OSA_Dashboard', 'osa_main.php'));
});
...

I tried asking ChatGPT or Copilot for the solution, but the solutions provided by them seem not to work.
I tried different tutorials and snippets to apply to the nginx configuration, but none of those worked.
Can you help me? Thank you so much!
